# JQuery Hide div not working

Tags: jquery

I have a div which I am trying to hide with a JQuery function;

```
function hideDiv() {

        $('SearchDiv').hide()
    }
```

This refers to the button;

```
<input type="button" style="width:170px; float:right;" value="Search" OnClick="hideDiv()"/>
```

The div looks like this;

```
<div id="SearchDiv"  style=" border-bottom: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: darkgrey; background-color: #F3F3F4; width: 100%; color: #4a3c8c; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 9pt;">TEST</div>
```

I have tried using the client ID, changing the button to an asp:button and still have no luck in showing the div! I have also looked through the forums here without finding anything that works for me.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are missing `selector` after adding `selector` it works fine.

See snippest.

```js
function hideDiv() {

        $('#SearchDiv').hide()
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="SearchDiv"  style=" border-bottom: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: darkgrey; background-color: #F3F3F4; width: 100%; color: #4a3c8c; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 9pt;">TEST</div>
<input type="button" style="width:170px; float:right;" value="Search" OnClick="hideDiv()"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

You're selecting elements of type `SearchDiv` where you should be selecting elements with ID `SearchDiv`:

```
$("#SearchDiv").hide();
```

See the [documentation for the ID selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) for more details.

Also, consider attaching the event in your code (so it still logically functions with JS disabled and to not mix concerns), this would remove the `OnClick` part and look like this:

```
// be sure to put the script tag at the end of your body section.
$("#SearchDiv").click(function(){
     $(this).hide();
});
```

It's also best practice to keep CSS in CSS files (and not inline) (or at least in a `style` tag), it'll improve performance and allow tweaking from the outside.